# Perl complaining of undefined subroutine, even though package in %INC

Tags: perl

Perl's namespace magic was always the most frustrating....

Have a script that relies on Recipient.pm, as well as Donation.pm

```
use lib '../BulkLoad';
use Recipient;
use Donation;
```

Recipient.pm is an object-orientated class, and itself uses Donation.pm (just a bundle of functions). Kinda recursive/redundant, I know.

My script - which again relies on both - is failing whenever it tries to gratuitously use a sub from Donation.pm:

```
my $city = Donation::getCity($dbh, $cityName, $stateName);
```

Perl complains:

```
Undefined subroutine &Donation::getCity called at ...
```

"Nice to have", "best practices" refactoring is out of scope :)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't provide the source for Donation one can only guess. It might be

- that the name of the function is different
- that your forgot to declare the package "Donation" in Donation.pm
- maybe something else (show the code)

Comment: Or possibly missing a statement returning a true value as the last statement in the package file.

Comment: @mwp: I doubt it because then it should have complained already that the 'use ...' failed, i.e. before the attempted function call.